# SSIS Excel source not mapping all columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a data that I need to import on a xlsx file.
The flow is simple, a person complete the information on this file, then put the file on a shared folder. Finally the ETL move the file to other location and load the data and put it on a SQL Table.

But for some strange reason now, the file load correct, but then fails. The error says

> SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Error in the validation of "component" Excel Origin "(150)". The validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA" was returned.

I realized that the dataource is not loading some columns that exists in the file.

I've tried creating a new datasource and new connection, but the problem persits. I think the problem is on the file, but how can I change the metadata to map the columns tha are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing then adding the `Excel Source` component in the DataFlow Task, Also try to set the DataFlow Task `Delay Validation` property to `True`

If the Error persists, i think that the issue is not with the columns name, it can be generated by the column data type, try adding `;IMEX=1` to the excel connection string so the data type are taken from the first row